# SharePoint WebService, Task creation assignedTo

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

I'm using the method UpdateListItems() from SharePoint WebService in order to create a new task.
In the task creation I put the field AssignedTo like this:

```
String.Format("<Field Name='AssignedTo'>{0}</Field>", assignTo)
```

When the value is something like ;#, (Example: 67;#Toto, Tutu), no problem.

The problem is that I use the Webservice in a C# console application and so I have no idea of what this number  could be. I retrieve the the login info from the active directory, but it seems that this number is specific for SharePoint (auto-increment).

Can somebody tell me more about this number and if there is a possibility to get it with the webservice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This number is the ID of the user in the SPWeb that lies in the context on your web service call. you can see this number in the url when you browser the user information (i.e. http://sharepointserver/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=67)

In order to create a proper string do the following

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(loginName);
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
string theCorrectAssignedToString = string.Format("{0};#{1}", user.ID, user.Name);
```

web - is the SPWeb object your list belongs to.

Correct the typos if any and you're good to go.